# Unity build with il2cpp. Error with Reflection.cpp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm getting random crashes of Unity app with this stack trace. Crash happens sometimes 30min after starting the app and sometimes couple hours after start.

I'm using Unity 2020.3.30f1 with HDRP 10.8.1, and all the drivers are up-to-date.

Anyone can help me with this?

```
    ========== OUTPUTTING STACK TRACE ==================

0x00007FFD776FECAE (GameAssembly) [C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.30f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\vm\Reflection.cpp:193] il2cpp::vm::Reflection::GetMethodObject 
0x00007FFD77629C2E (GameAssembly) [C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.30f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\il2cpp-api.cpp:883] il2cpp_method_get_object 
0x00007FFD7767E58A (GameAssembly) [C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.30f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\icalls\mscorlib\System.Reflection\MethodBase.cpp:137] il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Reflection::MethodBase::GetMethodFromHandleInternalType_native 
0x00007FFD78EEAABE (GameAssembly) [D:\VR PROJECTS\NewOnyx\Onyx4\Onyx - Copy\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\mscorlib10.cpp:30898] MethodBase_GetMethodFromHandleInternalType_native_m8B723E855637C9F9669090A2FB32BCAB9670748C 
0x00007FFD78EEAB7B (GameAssembly) [D:\VR PROJECTS\NewOnyx\Onyx4\Onyx - Copy\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\mscorlib10.cpp:30860] MethodBase_GetMethodFromHandleNoGenericCheck_m9917B4BD9F918BF6165558FAAB8AE3DE21E31FC3 
0x00007FFD79781D55 (GameAssembly) [D:\VR PROJECTS\NewOnyx\Onyx4\Onyx - Copy\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\mscorlib15.cpp:26084] RuntimeType_GetMethodsByName_m086C523B6F55A4E625CF849DA08BC77B6EA40DEE 
0x00007FFD7978114A (GameAssembly) [D:\VR PROJECTS\NewOnyx\Onyx4\Onyx - Copy\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\mscorlib15.cpp:18369] RuntimeType_GetMethodCandidates_mBCCD427577321475718FABC4457C80F6BF278E53 
0x00007FFD797820B7 (GameAssembly) [D:\VR PROJECTS\NewOnyx\Onyx4\Onyx - Copy\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\mscorlib15.cpp:19032] RuntimeType_GetMethods_m6EAC1990692B394BB4D83FEABDCF5D1C1886124D 
0x00007FFD771B88B1 (GameAssembly) [D:\VR PROJECTS\NewOnyx\Onyx4\Onyx - Copy\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\Newtonsoft.Json.cpp:66] VirtFuncInvoker1<MethodInfoU5BU5D_t86AA7E1AF11D62BAE3189F25907B252596FA627E * __ptr64,int>::Invoke 
0x00007FFD79DCB37C (GameAssembly) [D:\VR PROJECTS\NewOnyx\Onyx4\Onyx - Copy\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\mscorlib17.cpp:16602] StackTrace_GetFullNameForStackTrace_mB5F44F03311BCAFDF646EC7C1AE038C1677F24B4 
0x00007FFD79DCA806 (GameAssembly) [D:\VR PROJECTS\NewOnyx\Onyx4\Onyx - Copy\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\mscorlib17.cpp:16370] StackTrace_AddFrames_mBD56A1B153272A84AC74D0C04E4BB0B11227EFB8 
0x00007FFD79DCBFFC (GameAssembly) [D:\VR PROJECTS\NewOnyx\Onyx4\Onyx - Copy\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\mscorlib17.cpp:16967] StackTrace_ToString_m06C77719D4A613BF0B518946B57E934965220094 
0x00007FFD76E15788 (GameAssembly) [D:\VR PROJECTS\NewOnyx\Onyx4\Onyx - Copy\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\Unity.RenderPipelines.HighDefinition.Runtime5.cpp:34] VirtFuncInvoker0<String_t * __ptr64>::Invoke 
0x00007FFD79DCC071 (GameAssembly) [D:\VR PROJECTS\NewOnyx\Onyx4\Onyx - Copy\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\mscorlib17.cpp:16980] StackTrace_ToString_m878948A2563B5D53BB95BDFD4EE4ED3F46C188EB 
0x00007FFD79AD801F (GameAssembly) [D:\VR PROJECTS\NewOnyx\Onyx4\Onyx - Copy\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\mscorlib6.cpp:24586] Environment_GetStackTrace_mB72BDD4E80801D9151ADF1FA4484AC9C290CDCF5 
0x00007FFD78DAA60D (GameAssembly) [D:\VR PROJECTS\NewOnyx\Onyx4\Onyx - Copy\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\mscorlib7.cpp:32514] Exception_GetStackTrace_mD504F7EBBD67B2515BEC448A1C24396A49287A1F 
0x00007FFD78DABC7E (GameAssembly) [D:\VR PROJECTS\NewOnyx\Onyx4\Onyx - Copy\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\mscorlib7.cpp:32449] Exception_get_StackTrace_m66E7EFBB3658852BCB2960743DC9352D90C9EE48 
0x00007FFD76E15788 (GameAssembly) [D:\VR PROJECTS\NewOnyx\Onyx4\Onyx - Copy\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\Unity.RenderPipelines.HighDefinition.Runtime5.cpp:34] VirtFuncInvoker0<String_t * __ptr64>::Invoke 
0x00007FFD78B5A224 (GameAssembly) [D:\VR PROJECTS\NewOnyx\Onyx4\Onyx - Copy\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\UnityEngine.CoreModule2.cpp:32786] StackTraceUtility_ExtractStringFromExceptionInternal_mE6192186E0D4CA0B148C602A5CDA6466EFA23D99 
0x00007FFD76F915E2 (GameAssembly) [D:\VR PROJECTS\NewOnyx\Onyx4\Onyx - Copy\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Windows\x64\il2cppOutput\Il2CppInvokerTable.cpp:133062] RuntimeInvoker_FalseVoid_t700C6383A2A510C2CF4DD86DABD5CA9FF70ADAC5_RuntimeObject_VoidU2A_tC7FFEB695C165BD92A8656A0260E9CBC93892D9A_VoidU2A_tC7FFEB695C165BD92A8656A0260E9CBC93892D9A 
0x00007FFD7771014C (GameAssembly) [C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.30f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\vm\Runtime.cpp:568] il2cpp::vm::Runtime::Invoke 
0x00007FFD7762A36B (GameAssembly) [C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.30f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\il2cpp-api.cpp:1118] il2cpp_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FFD7CD2A998 (UnityPlayer) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007FFD7CD42E9C (UnityPlayer) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007FFD7CD2ACC5 (UnityPlayer) scripting_stack_trace_info_for
0x00007FFD7CD43AFF (UnityPlayer) Scripting::LogExceptionFromManaged
0x00007FFD7CD4394B (UnityPlayer) Scripting::LogException
0x00007FFD7CD42EF2 (UnityPlayer) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007FFD7C830C9F (UnityPlayer) ScriptableRenderContext::ExtractAndExecuteRenderPipeline
0x00007FFD7C4B4AFE (UnityPlayer) RenderManager::RenderCamerasWithScriptableRenderLoop
0x00007FFD7C4B4271 (UnityPlayer) RenderManager::RenderCameras
0x00007FFD7C945ED2 (UnityPlayer) PlayerRender
0x00007FFD7C941B20 (UnityPlayer) `InitPlayerLoopCallbacks'::`2'::PostLateUpdateFinishFrameRenderingRegistrator::Forward
0x00007FFD7C92DF0E (UnityPlayer) ExecutePlayerLoop
0x00007FFD7C92DFDF (UnityPlayer) ExecutePlayerLoop
0x00007FFD7C933F12 (UnityPlayer) PlayerLoop
0x00007FFD7C3561EA (UnityPlayer) PerformMainLoop
0x00007FFD7C35407B (UnityPlayer) MainMessageLoop
0x00007FFD7C3599CB (UnityPlayer) UnityMainImpl
0x00007FFD7C35A98B (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FF75F7811F2 (Onyx) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007FFDC44E7974 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFDC52FA2F1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

========== END OF STACKTRACE ===========
```

Comment: did you found something on that?

Comment: nope, it seems like the the ltsc version of the windows caused the problem. After switching to regular windows the crashing disappeared but Im still not completely sure if that was the cause

Comment: UNITY! IT caused by unity bugs